# Aligning separate tables <td> tags

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap. I have tables inside of `<td></td>` tags for the Status, Start Time and End Time column. Status column will always have a value. Start Time and End Time may or may not have a value. I need to ensure that the rows always stay aligned.
In this picture below, I want the grey boxes in Status, start Time and End Time to be aligned/same height.

```
     <tr>
        <td>{rowData.fileType}</td>
        <td>{rowData.fileName}</td>
        <td><table><tbody>{getStatusNames(rowData.statuses)}</tbody></table></td>
        <td><table><tbody>{getStatusStartTimes(rowData.statuses)}</tbody></table></td>
        <td><table><tbody>{getStatusEndTimes(rowData.statuses)}</tbody></table></td>
        <td>deltatimes</td>
        <td>{rowData.errorMessage}</td>
    </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: These are separate tables so they won't automatically align. Please show us the **CSS code** you have used to do this, so we can help you solve the problem you are having with it. (We are here to help you solve the problems, not write the code for you)

Answer (score 0):

I got a nice idea, you can utilize [rows span](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_td_rowspan.asp) for this. It's not answering the question in your title but it's solving your problem.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Favorite and Least Favorite Things</caption>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Bob</th>
    <th>Alice</th>
    <th>The End</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Favorite</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <td>Blue <br> color</td>
    <td>Purple</td>
    <th rowspan="4"> done </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Flavor</th>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>Chocolate <br> chips</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Least Favorite</th>
    <th>Color <br></th>
    <td>Yellow</td>
    <td>Pink</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Flavor</th>
    <td>Mint <br> cake</td>
    <td>Walnut</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```